# Prove that $ 4 + 3 \sqrt 2 $ is irrational

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation, rationality-testing

I am trying to prove by contradiction that $ 4 + 3 \sqrt 2 $ is irrational.
(I may use the fact that $ \sqrt 2 $ is irrational, and must use the definition of rational numbers.)

Proofs by contradiction always trip me up, and feel incomplete for some reason. Is the following correct? specifically is the last statement sufficient to contradict the assumption?

> Suppose not:
> Suppose $ 4 + 3 \sqrt 2 $ is rational.
> $$ ( 4 + 3 \sqrt 2 ) ^ 2 = \left( \frac p q \right ) ^ 2 $$
> $$ 34 + 24 \sqrt 2 = \frac { p ^ 2 } { q ^ 2 } $$
> $$ 24 \sqrt 2 = \frac { p ^ 2 } { q ^ 2 } - 34 $$
> $$ \sqrt 2 = \frac 1 { 24 } \left( \frac { p ^ 2 } { q ^ 2 } - 34 \right) $$
> which is a contradiction because irrational does not equal a rational number.

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? If $4+3\sqrt{2}$ is rational, so is $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: An irrational number plus a rational number is irrational, an irrational number times a rational number is irrational.

Comment: updated above, I figured starting with just the question would allow for a more free formed perspective of answers but I see that's not allowed.

Answer (score 3):

As @DietrichBurde hints, $4+3\sqrt{2}=\frac{a}{b}\iff\sqrt{2}=\frac{a-4b}{3b}$.

Comment: Thank you, very to the point here

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

Suppose there are $\;a,b\in\Bbb Z\;,\;\;b\neq0\;$ , s.t.

$$4+3\sqrt2=\frac ab \implies16+24\sqrt2+18=\frac{a^2}{b^2}\implies\ldots$$

Fill in the details in the above,,,and complete the very small ammount of work that is left to reach a contradiction.

Further Hint: there is a much easier, and direct, approach.

Comment: thank you, this answer makes me feel I was on the right track

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this well-known method:

$$x_1=4+3\sqrt 2 ~~~\text{and}~~~ x_2=4-3\sqrt 2$$

Then, you get

$$x^2-8x-2=0$$

By [Rational root theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) we deduce that $x=±1,±2$ are not the roots of the quadratic equation. This means,  both $x_1=4+3\sqrt 2 $ and $x_1=4-3\sqrt 2 $ are irrational.